# I can't get data from JSON and there is no error

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

i am trying get just one object from json file but can't. In the inspector, object is empty and when im trying to do something whit that object im getting null exception because of its empty. I also tried putting the object I was trying to retrieve in a list, but the list was still empty. Where is my mistake?
my Json file look like this:

```
{
   "Dialogue": {
     "npcName": "John",
     "sentences": [
       {
         "text1": "Hello, come here",
         "text2": "How do you feel",
         "text3": " good bye!"
       }
     ]
 
   }
 
 }
```

And this is my code:

```
 public TextAsset jsonScript;
 
     public Dialogue dialogue;
 
   void Start()
     {
  
         try
         {
 
             dialogue = JsonUtility.FromJson<Dialogue>(jsonScript.text);
             
         }
         catch (System.Exception error)
         {
 
             Debug.LogError(error);
         }
         
     }
```

Dialogue class:

```
 [System.Serializable]
 public class Dialogue 
 {
     public string npcName;
     public string[] sentences;
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sentences in your original json is an array of complex objects with properties `text1, text2, text3`

Your json should look like

```
{

     "npcName": "John",
     "sentences": [
       "Hello, come here", "How do you feel", " good bye!"
     ]
 
 }
```

To fit the `Dialogue` type.

Comment: Thank you so much its worked! But i dont get it why did it work when i deleted the name of the object (Dialogue)?

Comment: @cançağlarkırıcı - I think the answer is nesting. In the original example you had a JSON object that contained a Dialogue object, which contained a string and an array. In arynaq’s answer, the top level object was removed so all you had was an object with a string and an array, which fit the Dialogue model.

Comment: @suspicious_williams ohh I got it now. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

If changing the JSON (like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68518162/7111561)) is not an option then you would simply need one more wrapper class like

```
[Serializable] 
public class Root 
{
    public Dialogue Dialogue; 
}
```

to match your original JSON structure and do

```
dialogue = JsonUtility.FromJson<Root>(jsonScript.text).Dialogue;
```

instead.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is also a very logical solution.